# How long does it take for a new laptop battery to get charged?

Tags: battery, power, lenovo-laptop, charging

I just bought a new 6 cell Lenovo battery for my Ideapad. But it doesn't seem to get chraged. It's been an hour but there is no change in charge percentage. Is it normal for a new battery. At first I thought it must be an OS issue but the problem is same with both Linux and Windows.

Here's the image:

[image]

And this is what I get when I unplug the charger's cord:

[image]

What could possibly be the issue with a brand new Lenovo battery. I couldn't find any solution in battery replacement 101 guides. What if me using the laptop while the battery is getting charged for the first time is the issue? Should I just shut it down and wait for 5 to 10 hrs?

Comment: Did you buy an OEM battery or a 3rd party battery?

Comment: Of course an OEM battery.

Comment: Never mind. The problem has been solved. But thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: Glad you got it solved!

Comment: Probably, it is a drained battery and unfortunately you got that one. You must go for a replacement. You can plug the power adapter and use your laptop. But not recommended one. If you main power goes off then you will have abrupt shutdown of your laptop.

Comment: Cool. Glad that you got it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have waited longer. It takes some time to show the charge percentage. In my case it took 90 minutes with a new OEM battery.

[image]